# Pandas - stack multiindex header but exclude first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file which I read into a panda dataframe using a multiindex header.  Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,5,2,3], [2,10,4,20,3]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("1/1/2024","Store"), ("product code 1", "quantity onhand"), ("product code 1",'quantity sold'), ("product code 2", "quantity onhand"), ("product code 2",'quantity sold')))
df
```

| 1/1/2024 Store | product code 1 quantity onhand | product code 1 quantity sold | product code 2 quantity onhand | product code 2 quantity sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 10 | 4 | 20 | 3 |

The date in the first column is not needed.  I tried to stack, but I need to retain the store as it is.  Can this be done using pivot to get the following result?

```
data = [[1,'product code 1',5,5],[1,'product code 2',3,2],[2,'product code 1',4,10],[2,'product code 2',3,20]]
columns = ['Store','Code','quantity sold','quantity onhand']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df2
```

| Store | Code | quantity sold | quantity onhand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product code 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | product code 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | product code 1 | 4 | 10 |
| 2 | product code 2 | 3 | 20 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily set the first column as index, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
(df.set_index(df.columns[0])
   .stack(0)
   .rename_axis(['Store', 'Code'])
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   Store            Code  quantity onhand  quantity sold
0      1  product code 1                5              5
1      1  product code 2                2              3
2      2  product code 1               10              4
3      2  product code 2               20              3
```